# Web scraping using selenium in python, trouble in click the button

Tags: python, selenium, button, web-scraping

I am scraping the customer reviews from Wayfair (such as https://www.wayfair.com/appliances/pdp/bissell-aeroswift-compact-bagless-vacuum-bse10083.html). However, there are only 3 reviews listed on the first page, I need to "click" the button "show 10 more reviews" constantly by using Selenium.

The html corresponding to the button is: `<button data-hb-id="pl_button" class="Button Button--alternate Button--large Button--plainText" type="button"><span class="Button-content"><span><span class="pl-LoadingButton-content is-entered" style="transition: opacity 500ms ease-in-out 0s;"><div class="pl-Box--display-flex" data-hb-id="pl-box">Show 10 More<span class="SeeMoreReviewsButton-reviewsText">&nbsp;Reviews</span><svg focusable="false" viewBox="0 0 28 28" class="pl-BaseIcon pl-BaseIcon--scalable" aria-hidden="true" data-hb-id="pl-icon"><path d="M14 19a.47.47 0 01-.35-.15l-7-7a.49.49 0 01.7-.7L14 17.79l6.65-6.64a.49.49 0 11.7.7l-7 7A.47.47 0 0114 19z"></path></svg></div></span></span></span></button>`

I have tried it by using find_element_by_xPath, but the xPath keeps changes after several clicks:

```
element = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="bd"]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div/div[5]/div/div/button') 
element.click()
```

The variant xPath include:

```
//*[@id="bd"]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div/div[5]/div/div/button
//*[@id="bd"]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div/div[5]/div[1]/div/button
//*[@id="bd"]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div/div[4]/div/div/button
```

The other way of find elements, such as by class and by css selector doesn't work well either.

Does anyone have idea about how should I get the button element and click it?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example for continuously clicking that element.

```
url = "https://www.wayfair.com/appliances/pdp/bissell-aeroswift-compact-bagless-vacuum-bse10083.html"
driver.get(url)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver,10)
while True:
    try:
        wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//*[text()='Show 10 More']/ancestor::button" ))).click()
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        break
```

You constantly need to check if you can click button and then break out the loop when you get the error. Webdriver waits allow you to wait until the element is clickable and it also polls the dom for the element to be there as well.

Import

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It works very well for me.